# Does angular permit in-built reference for instances of ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, pug, angularjs-ng-repeat

Does angular distinguish b/w the instances of `p` below which we can refer to?

```
p(ng-repeat='item in items') {{item}}
```

The alternative would be to do something like

```
p(ng-repeat='item in items', id={{$index}}) {{item}}
```

to reference each repeat `p`. Does ng-repeat provide any in-built ability to reference, repeats?

PS:- code is written in jade.

equivalent html:- `<p ng-repeat='item in items', id={{$index}}> {{item}} </p>`

Comment: What do you want to do with the references to the `<p>`s?

Comment: DOM manipulation (inside directives), the id={{$index}} does not update, i guess i could do it with $observe or $watch. Just making sure.

Comment: Yes, better write a directive (e.g. for the content of the `<p>`s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upon inspection in the directive you have something like scope.$id which is unique for each repeat in ng-repeat.